# Flash: Download Dialog box

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, download

When a user clicks a certain link which contains an image that should be downloaded, the client wants a dialog box to appear.

Currently we zipped the downloadable files, but there is not other way in achieving this  than perhaps javascript right (or flash 10 filereference class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Did you take a look at the [`FileReference`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html) class, and in particular the [`download()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html#download()) member function? Also, [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/17_Networking_and_communications_7.html) link may be hepful. What problems, if any, are you facing with `FileReference`?